# fastboot boot boot.img failed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, android, ubuntu-20.04, adb

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and when trying to boot into, or flash, the TWRP recovery image I compiled, I receive error:

```bsh
$ fastboot boot boot.img
    downloading 'boot.img'...
    FAILED (command write failed (Success))
    finished. total time: 0.000s


$ fastboot flash boot boot.img
    downloading 'boot.img'...
    FAILED (command write failed (Success))
    finished. total time: 0.000s
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've voted to move this to the [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) site, however you'll likely find better support on the [XDA Forum](https://forum.xda-developers.com/) for the specific device model you're compiling for and would recommend copy/pasting this into a new thread there if you don't find what you're looking for through Thread Search. You'll also want to add additional info to the post, such as the device make and model, the steps you followed to compile the TWRP recovery image, any device-specific files you copied into the repo, and links to any guides used.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting that